# Disk root error on start instance on "Amazon Web Services (AWS)" EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I "Detach Volume" and "Attach Volume" again.

After that I want "Instance Start" but I get immediately message

> Error starting instances
>
> Invalid value 'i-{id}' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)

Q so where the error occured?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer is very easy,

when you "Attach Volume" again set parameter:

> Device: /dev/sda1

WARN! If you haven't own "Elastic Network Interface (ENI)" beware change of address on "Instance Start".

Thanks
[M. Brown](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=87644)

Comment: Lol, you're not pro, just my hero. :*

Comment: You're the man!

Comment: @israel.zinc happy to help you :-)

Comment: @Imran with pleasure have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

With /dev/sda1 won't work anymore. Directly specify xvda (just it, without /dev) on the Device field.

(well, seems a transient issue, this happened in Oregon region, I tried it in Ireland and you got to specify /dev/sda1 as usual)

Comment: it’s good to know for $oregon

Comment: It doesn't work either.